# React + Axios - Map returns is not a function?

Tags: reactjs, axios

I'm working on my first API with React. I am able to console log my current state after its loaded and the state for that array is set. However, running my component with a prop "FragrancesArray" which is set after loading the data from this.state.fragrances returns in not a function.

Using axios async and await.

No idea why? Can someone help?

Thanks.

My code:

```
// Core React
import React, { Component } from 'react';

// Axios
import axios from 'axios';

// Constants
import { FRAGRANCES_URL, BLOGS_URL, MAKE_UP_URL } from 'constants/import';

// Components
import Fragrances from 'components/Fragrances/Fragrances';

class App extends Component {

  state = {
    fragrances: [],
    blogs: [],
    makeup: []
  }

  getCoffee() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(() => resolve('☕'), 0); // it takes 1 seconds to make coffee
    });
  }

  async showData() {
    try {
      // Coffee first
      const coffee = await this.getCoffee();
      console.log(coffee); // ☕

      // Axios API's
      const fragranceData = axios(FRAGRANCES_URL);
      const blogData = axios(BLOGS_URL);
      const makeupData = axios(MAKE_UP_URL);

      // await all three promises to come back and destructure the result into their own variables
      await Promise.all([fragranceData, blogData, makeupData])

      .then((data) => {
        this.setState({
          fragrances: data[0],
          blogs: data[1],
          makeup: data[2]
        });

        const { blogs } = this.state;
        console.log(blogs);
      })

    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e); // 
    }

  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.showData();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Fragrances FragranceArray={this.state.fragrances} AppURL={FRAGRANCES_URL} />
    )
  }
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

In react, before you can set/use state, you need to declare it with `getInitialState()` but with ES6 class model you initialize state in a constructor.

```js
class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    //- Initialize default state values
    this.state = {
      fragrances: [],
      blogs: [],
      makeup: []
    }
  }
  
  //The rest of code stays the same.

    render() {
    return (
      <Fragrances FragranceArray={this.state.fragrances} AppURL={FRAGRANCES_URL} />
    )
  }
}
```

[More about React state](https://medium.com/react-tutorials/react-state-14a6d4f736f5)

Comment: using React 16 no need for constructor anymore and this.sate can be replaced with state. But it's not working tried thanks.

Comment: Mmmh, inside the render function can you `console.log(this.state.fragrances)`? and what's the output?

Comment: I get the data of my collection. However, i have noticed my API is an OBJECT an not an Array i'am looping using Map instead of Object. However, still i'm not able to retrieve the correct data inside the object. How can i convert Object to Array?

Comment: Oke, figured it out and solved.. setState should be fragrances: data not data[0]. I am able to show the data, however i am facing a small issue now with nested arrays. i need to use "fragrance.data.entries[index].name" inside my map in order to reach what i want. How can loop a map inside map? tnx man